# Have variables turn into an objects name

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a grid using PictureBoxes. A PictureBox name is pb11 (for 1,1 coordinates), pb21 etc.

I'm trying to do something like this:

pb(variable) or (variable)

The variable would be for example 11 or in example 2 pb11.

So rather than having to do this

```vb
If squaretobecoloured = 11 Then
    pb11.BackColor = Color.Red
ElseIf squaretobecoloured = 12 Then
    pb12.BackColor = Color.Red
End If
```

and continue it 100 times

Instead I would rather do something like this

```vb
pb(squaretobecoloured).BackColor = Color.Red
```

Just to clarify the picture boxes are from the toolbar and aren't created within the program.

Comment: The usual way would be to have an array of picturebox objects, not one variable per picturebox.

Comment: @AndrewMorton How would I implement that? How do you declare a picture box as an array? Thanks

Comment: [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: If you use the `TableLayoutPanel` option, that will take care of the visual layout of the controls and you can also index the table by column and row to get the control in a specific cell. Two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net languages do not convert strings to variables like that. Instead, you need to add your existing Pictureboxes to an array. This will allow you to reference them by index:

```
Dim pbGrid(,) As PictureBox = {
    {pb11, pb12},
    {pb21, pb22}
}
```

Note that the arrays will be 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed. Now you can do something like this:

```
pbGrid(0, 1).BackColor = Color.Red
```

or

```
Dim row As Integer = 0
Dim column As Integer = 1
pbGrid(row, column).BackColor = Color.Red
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy enough to do with the `recurse` option of [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=windowsdesktop-6.0):

```
squaretobecoloured = 11
Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find("pb" & squaretobecoloured, True).FirstOrDefault
If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf ctl Is PictureBox Then
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(ctl, PictureBox)
    pb.BackColor = Color.Red
Else
    MessageBox.Show("PB #" & squaretobecoloured & " not found!")
End If
```

If you want to combine this with the approach proposed by Joel Coehoorn, then you could build the 2D array in the `Load()` event of the Form by using nested loops for the X,Y values and searching for the PBs by name as I've done, then adding the found PBs into the correct locations of your 2D array. This way you can design the grid via the IDE on your Form and the code would automatically find them all at run-time instead of you hard-coding the names of all them into the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For i = 0 To 100
    Me.Controls("pb" & i).BackColor = Color.Red
Next
```